# Which are the C Standard rules for implicit type coversion?

Tags: c, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

i fund a post here in SO, that states some rules for implicit type conversion:

> — If both operands have the same type, no further conversion is needed.

> — Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank shall be converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.

> — Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater than or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, the operand with signed integer type shall be converted to the type of the operand with unsigned integer type.

> — Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, the operand with unsigned integer type shall be converted to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

> — Otherwise, both operands shall be converted to the unsigned integer type corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

My first question is, this are all the rules for integer conversion?

And my second question is, can you give me the rules for implicit conversion of floating point types?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) is incorrect if the types are smaller then `int`. Operands are promoted to `int` for the evaluation and then cast to the destination type. This allows a calculation to be performed correctly where an intermediate value would overflow the type. For example 8-bit values in `252 * 3 / 4`.

Comment: The c standard is the authoritative source.  It's relatively easy to read.  The rules for floating point are in section 6.3.1.4 and 6.3.1.5.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf

Comment: The rules for integers are in 6.3.1.3.